# Google play store won't let me download apps

Tags: google-play-store

Google Play Store is not letting me download a game for some reason I keep trying and every time it says the same thing it says something about the authentication I don't know what that means so it's hard for me to fix it if I don't know what it means and I definitely don't know where to look in the app's to fix it

Comment: You might not know what it means but at least you know what the error says. It's harder for us to fix it if we don't know what the error says. Could you [edit] the question and tell us exactly what it says, and when? (i.e. is it as soon as you click install, or after the download finishes, or some other time)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I did the following:

1. Clear cache for all apps.
2. Clear data in Google Play and Google Play Services
3. Logout of my Google Account, and login again.
4. Try installing the game.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Althoughh i only cleared cache of Google playstore, settings and Google services. Thanks a lot!